# How to get list of recource calendars by Google API?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I have available resource calendars that are located in Other Calendars > Interesting Calendars > Additional Calendars (approximately). I'm not subscribed to them yet.

When I try to get list of calendars I get only calendars I'm subscribed to.

Is there a Google Calendar API method available that will return list of my additional calendars, so I could subscribe to them?